# What is a histogram of a job a plot of, if not the squared amplitudes of the final state-vector?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

The histogram of a circuit is the result of running the circuit (with measurement) many times, right?

Does this correspond to the squared amplitudes of the final state-vector? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, probabilities shown in a histogram are squares of absolute values of coefficients in a state vector (i.e. probability amplitudes).

Note that the amplitudes are generally complex numbers, hence we square the absolute values and not the amplitudes themselves.